# Is loop fusion optimization supported in the Go (Golang) compiler?

Tags: loops, go, optimization, compiler-construction, compiler-optimization

I am working on optimizing my Go code and I want to know if the Go (Golang) compiler supports loop fusion optimization. Loop fusion is a technique that combines multiple loops into a single loop to improve performance by reducing memory access and loop overhead. I couldn't find any specific information about loop fusion optimization in the Go documentation or resources.

I have experimented with different loop structures and code rearrangements, but I haven't seen any significant performance improvements. I have also searched for compiler flags or settings related to loop fusion optimization, but I couldn't find any specific options. I was expecting that the Go compiler might perform loop fusion optimizations automatically or provide some means to enable or control this optimization, but I couldn't find any concrete information on this.

Comment: No mainstream compiler implements loop fusion. Not GCC or Clang either (which generally optimize much better than the default Go compiler), despite research projects to do that (eg Polly). Maybe some HPC compiler does it.

Comment: Loop fusion is *very* hard to prove correct for non-trivial cases.  And probably takes a lot of compile-time to search for candidates.  I expect that's why mainstream compilers don't do even try.

Comment: And regardless of whether it's easy or hard to prove correct, it's the kind of optimization that programmers should usually be deciding on by hand.  It could be worse for performance depending on cache effects and how many read and write streams each loop has.  Auto-vectorizing each loop separate is usually more profitable, so that's what highly-optimizing compilers try to do.

Comment: But yes, `a[i] += 1` / `a[i] *= 2` would be much more efficient in one pass than two (especially if the array doesn't fit in L1d cache), and could still auto-vectorize. So terrible code that did that in two loops could benefit from a compiler's help.  But is there much code like that, with so much low-hanging fruit for a loop-fusion pass?  Probably not, otherwise I'd guess one of GCC or clang would have one by now for trivial cases where the loop bounds are the same and the array is the same, and ops are pure vertical.